# Update field status based on checked button

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

i got problem to use check button to update status(hold/process) directly (without save/submit button in edit form). i want to make this because i want to change status for several list based on checked list. My question, how to use my javasrcypt in the below to implement what i want?
i've code like this, i edited from original source (for multiple delete), i use same code but for change status, now my problem is i can't change status (hold/process)

**Javascrypt :**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.hold").click(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure want to change status to HOLD?"))
    {
        id_array=new Array()
        i=0;
        $("input.chk:checked").each(function(){
            id_array[i]=$(this).val();
            i++;
        })

        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>app_plan/hold_multiple',
            data:"kode="+id_array,
            type:"POST",
            success:function(respon)
            {
                if(respon==1)
                {
                    window.parent.location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        })
    }
        return false;
    })
})
</script>
```

**My class button :**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary hold"><div class="btn-hold">Hold</div></a>
```

**Controller :**

```
public function hold_multiple()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="")
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('kode');
        $upd['stts_prg'] = 'hold';
        $query = $this->db->query("update from report_oa_plan where id_plan IN (".$id.")", $upd);
        if($query){
            echo 1;
        }
        else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:'.base_url().'');
    }
}
```

If there any idea to solve my code or if there another solution (maybe with toggle switch) it's no problem, i need your feedback, thanks...

Comment: What is the error are you getting in?

Comment: i can't change status hold or process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already solved with this code :

```
    public function hold_multiple()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="")
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('kode');
        $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE report_oa_plan SET stts_prg = 'Hold' WHERE id_plan IN (".$id.")");
        if($query){
            echo 1;
        }
        else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:'.base_url().'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this shortest way

```
public function hold_multiple()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="")
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('kode');
        $upd['stts_prg'] = 'hold';
        $this->db->where_in('id_plan',$id);
        $this->db->update('report_oa_plan',$upd);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        {
            echo 1;
        }
        else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:'.base_url().'');
    }
}
```

Comment: i already tried this, nothing happen, maybe in js scrypt there's something to edit too?

Comment: Print post variable `print_r($_POST)` in controller and check what are you getting.

Comment: I have update the answer.Hope this will solve your issue. @karisma

Comment: it's change, but just the first list changed, for example, i checked id_plan number 25, 26 and 27, after i click hold button, just number 25 changed the status into hold, another id_plan not changed...

Comment: can you print id `$id = $this->input->post('kode');`  and post here what are you getting?

Comment: Print it by `print_r($id)` in your controller below this line `$id = $this->input->post('kode');`

Comment: sorry, late for answer, i already print it, it shown ids from selected list that i checked..
i think problem maybe come from edit `$upd['stts_prg'] = 'hold';` then save it to sql based on id_plan selected...